# Prevent Neovim LSP from opening a scratch preview buffer

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, lsp

When auto-completing with neovim's LSP, whenever selecting a menu entry from the auto-complete list a scracth/preview buffer is created, even if empty:

[image]

How can I disable these buffers specifically for auto-completion ?

I'm aware of `previewheight`; setting it to 0 doesn't seem to have any effect, and even if it would, it would disable the preview buffer everywhere whereas I just want it disabled for auto-completion.

Comment: Try `:help 'completeopt'`, though IDK if NeoVim baked in the `preview` flag there or not.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yep, `completeopt` exists and defaults to `menu,preview`; setting it to `menu` fixes the issue; if you make that into an answer i'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `:set completeopt-=preview` to remove this behavior.